# Setting of Background-image

Tags: css

I have some problems with my `background-image` setting.
Does someone know why `.box-3` is not pushing `.box-2` away?

```css
 .box-1 {
      height: 250px;
      width: 100%;
      background-image: url(https://article.images.consumerreports.org/prod/content/dam/CRO%20Images%202017/Magazine-Articles/April/Google-Auto-Profile-images-2017/PRF-203);
    }

    .box-2 {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: #000;
      color: #fff;
      
    }
```

```html
<div class="box-1">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur 
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur 
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

    <div class="box-2">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The min-height of `box-1` is preventing it to become higher, change the `height: 250px` to `min-height: 250px`

```
.box-1 {
    min-height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(https://article.images.consumerreports.org/prod/content/dam/CRO%20Images%202017/Magazine-Articles/April/Google-Auto-Profile-images-2017/PRF-203);
}

.box-2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! On my background-image i have two div boxes which are floatet with the bootstrap grid system. My problem is that when i it comes to smaller screens the right one of the two div boxes jumps under the left one (which is fine) but it's not pushing the .box-2 away. I have no idea why

Comment: can't you show the code with the div boxes and their bootstrap classes?

Comment: It's because of the `height:250px` change it to `min-height:250px`, I'll edit the answer, if is It correct, choose it